# How can i access the className in a functional component from sass file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

When I add style via html elements like `<div>` or body it works, but when I use `.container` to style I can't see the changes, any help will be appreciated

My `authLayout.scss`

```
@import './variables.scss';

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

My component

```
import React from 'react';
import '../assets/scss/authLayout.scss';


export default function AuthLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>THIS THE AUTH LAYOUT</h1>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine..make sure that the path in `import '../assets/scss/authLayout.scss';` is correct.

Comment: @Ramesh the path exists, I am even using the autocomplete to get it

Comment: Do you have a proper pre processor in place. Maybe node-sass or something ?

Comment: @Knick I had it working by replacing where I declare the class name in the component by {style.container} `style is the imported sass`.
Now is it the normal behavior of using sass with react or there is another way of not doing that much

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have installed node-sass in your React project.
   If not then in terminal use the command
   **npm install node-sass -S**
2. Change all **.css** file extension with **.scss**
3. Change any imports to use **.scss**
4. Now for **@import "./variables.scss";**, 
   Keep the **variables.scss** file directly in your src folder(to provide an absolute path) and do the import in your **authLayout.scss** file as follows:
   **@import "variables.scss";** i-e., withour ./ (which means a relative path).
5. Lastly make sure  **import '../assets/scss/authLayout.scss';** path is correct.

Hope that will help. For further resource visit: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-in-create-react-app-v2

Comment: I had it working by replacing where I declare the class name in the component by {style.container} style is the imported sass. Now is it the normal behavior of using sass with react or there is another way of not doing that much